# Regex.Match returns different/wrong result in Unity compared to same exact code in a C# console app

Tags: c#, regex, unity-game-engine, match

I'm trying to get matches on a string in Unity using a Regular Expressions pattern. I've written the whole code inside a sample project and it worked perfectly fine.

```
tokens[line] = Regex.Matches(instructionLines[line], "^\\w*|(?<=q\\[)\\d*(?=\\]))";
```

I have validated that it matches what I need with [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/FzpZXq/1).

I have then printed out the result in my console, which was also correct.

```
Console App:
 h 0
 h 1
 h 2
 h 3
 cx 1 2
 t 1
```

Finally, I copy-pasted the code in Unity - and it doesn't match the first word of the line like it did in the sample project.

```
Unity Console:
 0
 1
 2
 3
 1 2
 1
```

I didn't change anything, the imports are the same (using System.Text.RegularExpressions;) and the regex is correct. Why does Unity do this, and how do I fix this incorrect behaviour?

Comment: Try it adding multiline `(?m)^[a-z]*|(?<=q\[)\d*(?=\])`

Comment: This worked, thank you very much! Please feel free to answer the question.

Comment: Yes @Thefourthbird please ad this as an answer and maybe explain a bit how exactly it fixes the issue

Comment: @makssyz You might like to know about all the regex options available with .NET: [Regular Expression Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options).

Comment: @makssyz In the link you added to your question https://regex101.com/r/FzpZXq/1 you can see at the right top that there is an `m` flag for multiline. As your pattern uses an anchor `^` you have to enable multiline, which can also be done using an inline modifier `(?m)` See https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed thanks to @Thefourthbird, to quote from comments:

> Try it adding multiline (?m)^[a-z]*|(?<=q[)\d*(?=])
>
> In the link you added to your question regex101.com/r/FzpZXq/1 you can
> see at the right top that there is an m flag for multiline. As your
> pattern uses an anchor ^ you have to enable multiline, which can also
> be done using an inline modifier (?m) See
> regular-expressions.info/anchors.html